# Automatically reference bower package in ember-cli-build.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, bower, ember-cli, bower-install

When you add a library using bower, that is not an ember addon, you have to manually add it to the `ember-cli-build.js` using `app.import`. For eg. if I add a typical js library I have to add both the css and js files like:

```
app.import('../path_to/library.min.js');
app.import('../path_to/library.min.css');
```

**Question**: Is there any way to automate this process? With all these nice utilities we have for front-end development, there must surely be?

Answer (score -3):

I don't know any way of automating these processes.